# Copy Firefox 69.0 profile from Ubuntu to Win 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, firefox

I'm having hard time copying my Firefox profile from Ubuntu to Win 10. Both systems have Firefox 69.0 installed. When I copy over the entire profile from Ubuntu to Win 10, Firefox recognizes the profile but welcomes me with error:

[image: Firefox sucks!]

Any troubleshooting ideas? Can I force Firefox to open that profile anyway or maybe what should I manually modify in my profile to make it work?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why don't you simply utilize Firefox Sync, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `-allow-downgrade` launch option to force Firefox to launch my profile anyway. Everything works as intended.

Comment: Thanks to therube_agone for helping me find the launch option!